# php function to extract link from string

Tags: php

i want to extract href link from text or string. i write a little function to do that but this is slow when a string to transform is large. My code is

```
function spy_linkIntoString_Format($text) {
    global $inc_lang; $lang = $inc_lang['tlang_media'];
    $it = explode(' ' ,$text);
    $result = '';
    foreach($it as $jt) {
        $a = trim($jt);
        if(preg_match('/((?:[\w\d]+\:\/\/)?(?:[\w\-\d]+\.)+[\w\-\d]+(?:\/[\w\-\d]+)*(?:\/|\.[\w\-\d]+)?(?:\?[\w\-\d]+\=[\w\-\d]+\&?)?(?:\#[\w\-\d]*)?)/', $jt)) {
            $pros_lis = str_replace('www.','',$jt);
            $pros_lis = (strpos($pros_lis, 'http://') === false ? 'http://'. $pros_lis : $pros_lis);
            $urlregx = parse_url($pros_lis);
            $host_name = (!empty($urlregx['host']) ? $urlregx['host'] : '.com');
            if($host_name == 'youtube.com') {
                $string_v = $urlregx['query']; parse_str($string_v, $outs); $stID = $outs['v'];
                $result .= '<a title="Youtube video" coplay="'.$stID.'" cotype="1" class="media_spy_vr5" href="#"><span class="link_media"></span>'.$lang['vtype_youtube'].'</a> ';
            } elseif($host_name == 'vimeo.com') {
                $path_s = $urlregx['path']; $patplode = explode("/", $path_s); $stID = $patplode[1];
                $result .= '<a title="Vimeo video" coplay="'.$stID.'" cotype="2" class="media_spy_vr5" href="#"><span class="link_media"></span>'.$lang['vtype_vimeo'].'</a> ';
            } elseif($host_name == 'travspy.com') {
                $result .= '<a href="'.$jt.'" title="'.$pros_lis.'" ><span class="jkt_445 jkt_3256 c8_big_corner"></span>'.$pros_lis.'</a> ';
            } else {
                $result .= '<a href="'.$jt.'" title="'.$pros_lis.'" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><span class="jkt_445 c8_big_corner"></span>'.$pros_lis.'</a> ';
            }
        } else {
            $result .= $jt.' ';
        }
    }
    return trim($result);/**/
}
```

Can i do this run fast?

Answer (score 5):

You should rewrite this to use `preg_match_all`instead of splitting the text into words (i.e. drop the `explode`).

```
$regex = '/\b((?:[\w\d]+\:\/\/)?(?:[\w\-\d]+\.)+[\w\-\d]+(?:\/[\w\-\d]+)*(?:\/|\.[\w\-\d]+)?(?:\?[\w\-\d]+\=[\w\-\d]+\&?)?(?:\#[\w\-\d]*)?)\b/';
preg_match_all($regex, $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $url = $match[0];
    // your link generator
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be breaking the text into words separated by spaces, and then matching each word against a regular expression. This is very time consuming indeed.
A faster way to do this is to perform the regular expression search on the entire text and then iterate over it's results.

```
preg_match_all($regex, $text, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
foreach($result[0] as $jt){
    //do what you normally do with $jt
}
```

Comment: this ok but i want to return text that not contain link. how to do this with a Regex

Comment: You can do preg_replace_all($regex, "", $text) which will delete all patterns that match $regex. However this is a little dangerous as it may delete more than you were counting on.